# HTML5 picture and source element

Tags: html, image

I have written these lines in a HTML file in the order to change the picture if the orientation is changed.

```
<picture>
    <source media="all and (orientation: landscape)" srcset="images/images/images_of_teaching/futas_running_720w.jpg 720w, images/images/images_of_teaching/futas_running_1080w.jpg 1080w">
    <source media="all and (orientation: portrait)" srcset="images/images/images_of_teaching/iras_writing_720w.jpg 720w, images/images/images_of_teaching/iras_writing_1080w.jpg 1080w">
</picture>
```

But it does not work. Could you help me out please?

Thank you

Comment: If I use the Google Development tools I can see the size of each picture is 0px x 0px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you specify a img tag inside of your picture tag:

```
<picture>
    <source media="all and (orientation: landscape)" srcset="your image">
    <source media="all and (orientation: portrait)" srcset="your-other image">
    <img src="your-main-image.extension" alt= "Your image quick description"/>
</picture>
```

Comment: Glad if it helped ;)

Comment: An empty `<img />` is also enough since it's used as the container for the matching `<source>`